# updateSelectInput label doesn't accept HTML tags?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm having a problem with the combination of "selectInput" and "updateSelectInput" in my Shiny App (I'm new to Shiny, but can't seem to find an answer to that question anywhere). I want to format the label with html tags as in the basic example below (e.g. split between two lines, change font size). This works just fine for the "selectInput", but the "updateSelectInput" cannot digest the same label and it outputs "[object Object]". It seems to me that it cannot deal with html tags. Is there any workaround for that??? Thanks!

**ui.R:**

```
# Load libraries needed for app
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# Define the overall UI with a dashboard page template
shinyUI(
   dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(title = "dashboard header"),
      dashboardSidebar( 
         #Create first dropdown box
         selectInput("choice1", "First choice:",1:5,selected=NULL),

         #Create second dropdown box
         selectInput("choice2",  p("Then, make your ", tags$br(), tags$small("second choice")), c("a","b","c","d","e"))
      ),
      dashboardBody()
   ) 
)
```

**server.R:**

```
# Load libraries needed for app
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# Define server for the Shiny app
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
   # populate second dropdown box when a choice in first dropdown box is made
   observe({
      updateSelectInput(session, "choice2", p("Then, make your ", tags$br(), tags$small("second choice")), c("a","b","c","d","e"))
   })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear in your description/code  what you want to accomplish. That being said, you are note changing the label in updateSelectInput, so no need to repeat the label in the update command. Also there is no input in your observe(, it will do nothing. I change the code to be reactive to input$choice1, But you need to add some code to update the choices in choice2.

You may also use renderUI/uiOutput to update controls in the server, then you will avoid issues with the label.

```
# Load libraries needed for app
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# Define server for the Shiny app
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
   # populate second dropdown box when a choice in first dropdown box is made
   observeEvent( input$choice1  ,{
      updateSelectInput(session = session,
                        inputId =  "choice2",
                       # label = p("Then, make your ", tags$br(), tags$small("second choice")),
                        choices = c("a","b","c","d","e"))
   })
}) 


# Define the overall UI with a dashboard page template
ui <- shinyUI(
   dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(title = "dashboard header"),
      dashboardSidebar( 
         #Create first dropdown box
         selectInput(inputId = "choice1",
                     label = "First choice:",
                     choices = 1:5,
                     selected=NULL),

         #Create second dropdown box
         selectInput(inputId = "choice2",
                     label = p("Then, make your ",    tags$br(),  tags$small("second choice")),
                     choices =  c("a","b","c","d","e"))
      ),
      dashboardBody()
   ) 
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks so much for your quick reply. First, commenting out the label in updateSelectInput solved my problem!!! Although I still don't understand why it would not accept the same thing that selectInput accepts in the first place - any ideas?. I did not include anything in the observe because it was besides the point, but I suppose I could have completely removed that then. Thanks again!

Comment: updateSelectInput is tricky. You can also set label= NULL in selectInput and add the label as an html paragraph above the control in UI, or in server using renderUI/uiOutput.  I usually do that as is much more flexible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40341804/r-shiny-updateselectizeinput-custom-html-tags-for-labels gives a solution to updating the label using `shinyjs::html("labelText", "<b>second choice</b>")`, as long as you put the label into e.g. `div("First choice:", id = "labelText")`.