# R shiny updateSelectizeInput custom HTML tags for labels

Tags: shiny, selectize.js

Is there a way to use HTML tags (e.g. h6) for updateSelectizeInput (which is working for selectInput, see code below)? With the code below simply using h6("Label") in the updateSelectizeInput [object Object] is shown as output.

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)



ui =fluidPage(
  selectizeInput('DropDownSelectize',choices=NULL,label=""),
  selectInput('DropDownSelect',choices = c("choice1","choice2","choice3"),
  label=h6("Label"))
 )

server = function(input, output, session) {

 observe({
   updateSelectizeInput(session, 
                     'DropDownSelectize',
                      label = h6("Label"),
                      choices = c("choice1","choice2","choice3"),
                      selected = "choice1",
                      server = TRUE)

 })


}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Thanks

Comment: This pretty clearly appears to be a bug. If you wrap the `h6` in the update in `as.character` you get the `h6` tag literally. I will file bug report on github

Comment: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1451

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the label is going to be always the same, just don't set a value for `label` on `updateSelectizeInput`. Actually, you should only set the parameters that you want to change.

By instance, this is only changing the selected value:

```R
updateSelectizeInput(session, 'DropDownSelectize', selected = "choice3")
```

If the value of `label` needs to be changed but with a tag or style, like in this case `h6`, you can use `shinyjs` to change only the text of the label. For that purpose you need to add an `id` to the `h6` tag. See the example below where inside the first observer the label is changed using the `html` function of `shinyjs`. I also added two buttons to manually change the text of the label.

```R
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui =fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(), # to initialize shinyjs
  selectizeInput('DropDownSelectize',choices=NULL,label=h6("", id = "labelText")),
  selectInput('DropDownSelect',choices = c("choice1","choice2","choice3"),
  label=h6("Label")),
  actionButton("useLabel1", "Use Label 1"),
  actionButton("useLabel2", "Use Label 2")
 )

server = function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 
                     'DropDownSelectize',
                      # label = h6("Label"), # no needed 
                      choices = c("choice1","choice2","choice3"),
                      selected = "choice1",
                      server = TRUE)
    shinyjs::html("labelText", "Label")
  })

  observeEvent(input$useLabel1, {
    shinyjs::html("labelText", "Label 1")
  })  

  observeEvent(input$useLabel2, {
    shinyjs::html("labelText", "Label 2")
  })  

}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```